# Make CKEditor ignore widget content

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

The HTML inside the `aside` isn't editable but CKEditor still runs the content filter and removes tags and shows hidden input fields.

The relevant HTML widget code is as follows:

```
<aside class="widget widget-form" contenteditable="false" data-widget-id="12" id="widget-4564" style="width: 40%; float: left;">
    // my form HTML goes here
</aside>
```

The relevant CKEditor widget code is as follows:

```
template : 
    '<aside class="widget" contenteditable="false" style="width: 50%; float: left;" id="widget-'+Date.now().toString().substring(Date.now().toString().length-4)+'">\
        New Widget\
    </aside>',
allowedContent : true,
upcast: function( element ) {
    if ( element.name == 'aside' && element.hasClass( 'widget' ) )
        return true;
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically my solution to this problem was to load the widget's content after CKEditor has loaded.

In the widget plugin I used the init function like so:

```
init : function() {

    window.element = $(this.element.$);

    $.get("/_includes/_.aspx", {
            'q' : 'widget_get',
            'id' :  element.data('widget-id')
        }).always(function(data){

        element.html(data);

    });
},
```

I use jQuery to load the contents of the widget after CKEditor has loaded.

When I save my editor's content (on the server side) I Regex out all the widget's content and leave only references.

On non-edit load I replace those references with the complete widget.

On edit load I replace those references with my empty `<aside>` tag with the widget guts loading after CKEditor has loaded from the `init` function above.

My aside tags are recognized by CKEditor as widgets using [`upcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget).

Loading the Widget guts after CKEditor means the widget appears exactly as it does with CKEditor not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're overusing CKEditor a little bit. You load into it parts that should be either edited in separate editors or not edited at all. You need to remember that CKEditor is not a website builder, hence not everything should be loaded into it.

As for this case, I see at least two solutions.

### Use placeholder

Instead of loading entire form into that floated container, write a simple widget which will contain just an information for what that placeholder is. The data should look like:

```
<p>Some editable text...</p>
<div data-placeholder="formTest"></div>
<p>More editable text</p>
```

You'll be able to do that very easily with widgets. Then, in your application replace the placeholder with what it stands for. This way you'll keep your database clear and therefore editor's contents too.

### Use placeholder in data, but load the content into the ready widget

As widget controls its state you can load a piece of rich content inside it dynamically, but still have clear, semantic content.

So, the data will look like in previous case, however, you'll replace it with the preview of the form section in widget's init. It could look like this:

```
editor.widgets.add( 'sectionPlaceholder', {
    upcast: function( el ) {
        return el.name == 'div' && el.attributes[ 'data-placeholder' ];
    },
    init: function() {
        // Lock & unclock to prevent recording a separate snapshot for
        // loading preview step.
        editor.fire( 'lockSnapshot' );
        // Retrieve section HTML from some application's object or method.
        this.element.setHtml( sectionsHtml[ this.element.data( 'placeholder' ) ] );
        editor.fire( 'unlockSnapshot' );
    }
    ...
    // Since you're loading some forms, you may want to completely covers them.
    mask: true
 } );
```

### The general idea

Editor should be used to edit content of atomic page fragments, not the entire page at once. Data saved into database should not mix those things too.

Comment: From the screenshot you assumed that I am editing the entire page with CKeditor; I am not. Beyond that you make valid points. Loading the widget's content after CKeditor makes sense. I will give it a try and report back.